# Redirect between HTTP and HTTPS with [RequireHttps] failed with IIS Express

Tags: https, iis-express, requirehttps

I'm tried using IIS Express. ( change from previous use Local IIS ) . 
I have redirect problem.

For example
step 1:
go to login page https://localhost/user/index , i got "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

step 2: when I change in type direct url to https://localhost:44300/user/index
the login page is display fine

step 3: After input username and pw , ( url is now localhost/home/index ) , the login page is hang!

step 4: when I type change in url to "localhost:61025/" the home page is display

step 5: when I click at logout menu, i got  "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"
step 6: when I type change url  to https with port number 44300 , the logout page sucessful display

---

the both http en https page work fine
but I don't know how to redirect between from http and https
( with previous "Local IIS" work fine )

---

I have in  c:\users[my name]\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config already binding

```html
<bindings>
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61025:localhost" />
 <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

my javascript code in index.cshtml

```js
function dologout(result) {
        if (result == 'yes') {
            localStorage.clear();
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            document.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/user/logout")';
        }
    }
```

the both page work fine with ISS Express en SSL
but the redirect between http en https failed

Please help me, Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: You must let your own code work well with port number other than 80, or 443. Without that it won't work well on IIS Express.

Comment: Hi Lex Li,
Thank you for your reply. My code work well with Local IIS before I change to using IIS Express.

Comment: I have setup > Internet Information Services> Expand World Wide Web Services > Expand Common HTTP Features, and then enable HTTP Redirection. 

I have in web.config

`<rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS " stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_HOST}:44300" redirectType="Permanent"  />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>`

but still not redirect from http to https